# DB2 How to test status of cursor

Tags: db2

I have tried to use an IBM site suggested approach to test the status of a DB2 cursor using a 'predicate' which I show below. But it will not survive compilation in my COBOL program:
IF ('cursor' IS NOT OPEN) THEN
     OPEN 'cursor'
  ELSE 
     CLOSE 'cursor'
     OPEN 'cursor'
  END IF;
I presumed it needed EXEC SQL and END EXEC around the OPEN and CLOSE
but does not solve it:
IF READCUR IS OPEN
    EXEC SQL
        CLOSE READCUR
        OPEN READCUR
    END-EXEC
ELSE
    EXEC SQL
        OPEN READCUR
    END-EXEC
END-IF
Pre-compiler says: "" REQUIRED
INVALID KEYWORD "OPEN"; 
Is it even possible in COBOL to use this simple approach to determining cursor status ??

Answer (score 0):

Each of the "CLOSE READCUR" or "OPEN READCUR" should have their own EXEC-SQL, END-EXEC. It will not process them alltogether

Comment: When I do add an EXEC-SQL and an END-EXEC it satisfies the DB2 Pre-compiler but COBOL throws an error on the "IF" claiming that RREADCUR is undefined. However it is defined, albeit with an EXEC-SQL preceding it as in:    EXEC SQL                         
  DECLARE READCUR CURSOR FOR     
    SELECT

Comment: @SeruSher                                     
100-OPEN.                    
    IF READCUR IS OPEN       
       EXEC SQL              
           CLOSE READCUR     
       END-EXEC              
       EXEC SQL              
           OPEN READCUR      
       END-EXEC              
    ELSE                     
       EXEC SQL              
           OPEN READCUR      
       END-EXEC              
    END-IF

Comment: @SeruSher EXEC SQL                      
  DECLARE READCUR CURSOR FOR  
      etc. etc.
END-EXEC

100-OPEN.                       
    IF READCUR IS OPEN          
       EXEC SQL                 
           CLOSE READCUR        
       END-EXEC                 
       EXEC SQL                 
           OPEN READCUR         
       END-EXEC                 
    ELSE                        
       EXEC SQL                 
           OPEN READCUR         
       END-EXEC                 
    END-IF